# How can I save values of editText that are dynamically created in a dialog Window within an xml file? - Android

Tags: android

I have created 2 classes and one Interface. One Interface that handles dialog clicks,a MainActivity class that hold a button and a textView. The MainActiviy class instantiates my second class(FireMissilesFragment) which contains an AlertDialog as a fragment.  In the FireMisslesFragment I have dynamically created EditText. The problem with my app is that when I call (onsavenstancestate) in my mainActivity class in which FireMissilesFragment is instantiated in, i try to save my editText values so that when the popup closes and I restart it, the values of editText will maintain it's values once the popup opens again.

I have tried (onSaveInstanceState) method and the values hold;however, it is yet possible for me to recreate what was destroyed  once the dialog is initiated again.Can Someone please shed some light on this matter.

Here is my code:

//===============================Interface=====================================//

```
        public interface NoticeDialogListener {
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog,EditText[] editText);
public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog);
     }
```

//==========================MainActivity Class=============================//

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;


          public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements   `               NoticeDialogListener{ 

     private  EditText[] _edText;
     private TextView _tv;

     private Multiplication multi;
     private Double[] s;
     private String s1;
     public static final String _SCORE1 = "score1";
     public static final String _SCORE2 = "score2";


     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                _tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
               Button dAction = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

                  s = new Double[2];


             dAction.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {//open();
        confirmFireMissiles();


        }

              });//ssetOnclickLi...
    ///success thank god.

            //===================================================//


              }
      public void confirmFireMissiles() {

    DialogFragment newFragment = new FireMissilesDialogFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"ff");

         }//confirmFireMisslesClosing brace

         // The below is what happens when the Button "multiply" in 
             Dialog window pops up.
@Override
public void onDialogPositiveClick(DialogFragment dialog,EditText[] 
                     editText) {    


    _edText = editText; // is this association

         multi = new Multiplication();
       try{ 
      // gets the text and stores to string array.

          s[0]=Double.parseDouble(_edText[0].getText().toString());
     s[1]=Double.parseDouble(_edText[0].getText().toString());
     Log.d("hello", String.valueOf(s[0]));


    }catch(NumberFormatException e){
              _tv.setText("please Insert an Number and calculate  again"); // 
        Log.d("Error", "place in numbers please");
    } 
        s1 = String.valueOf(multi.multiply(s[0],s[1]));
        //set Textview to s1.
                 _tv.setText(s1);
             }
@Override
public void onDialogNegativeClick(DialogFragment dialog) {}
```

}

//================================================================================//
    public class FireMissilesDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
        private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
        private EditText[] _edText;  // enable when ready
        private NoticeDialogListener _mListener;
        public static final String _SCORE1 = "score1";
        public static final String _SCORE2 = "score2";
        private Double[] s;

```
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
        builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
           //shows added content to dialog.
     //  d = new String[2];
             s = new Double[2];




    if(savedInstanceState !=null){


   s[0] =  Double.parseDouble(savedInstanceState.getString(_SCORE1));
  s[1] = Double.parseDouble(savedInstanceState.getString(_SCORE2));
       Log.d("Hey",String.valueOf(s[0]));

     _edText[0].setText(String.valueOf(s[0]));
        showIt();



    }else{
         showIt();

    }
          //sets the characterisitcs of  the dialogue.
        builder.setTitle("We are all stars of the show.");
        builder.setMessage( "we are strong")

             .setPositiveButton("Multiply", new  
               DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    // enable when ready


   _mListener.onDialogPositiveClick(FireMissilesDialogFragment.this,_edText); 

                   }
               });

        // Create the AlertDialog object and return it

             return builder.create();
    }

 public  void showIt(){
```

// This piece of code creates a Linear layout that is suppose to show in a dialogue popup.
          LayoutParams param = new
                   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1.0f);
             LinearLayout layout= new LinearLayout(getActivity());
             layout.setLayoutParams(param);
             layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
             layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

```
          // Dynamically place EditText efficiently Inside Linear Layout.
          _edText = new EditText[4];
           for (int i = 0;i< _edText.length;i++) {

         _edText[i] = new EditText(getActivity());
         _edText[i].setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | 
              InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL); 
         _edText[i].setTextSize(20)
        try{
         s[i] =Double.parseDouble(   
                                  _edText[i].getText().toString());
        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
        //  Log.d("hello", "wrong input");
        }
         layout.addView(_edText[i]);
            }
         builder.setView(layout);
            }
   //============================================== Look over this code======////////////
   @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
       super.onAttach(activity);
         //Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
        try {
          //   Instantiate the NoticeDialogListener so we can send events to the host
            _mListener = (NoticeDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                   + " must implement NoticeDialogListener");
        }
    }


       @Override
   public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Save the user's current game state

            savedInstanceState.putDouble(_SCORE1,s[0]);
        savedInstanceState.putDouble(_SCORE2,s[1]);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

}
```

Comment: You could probably use `SharedPreferences` and store the information there, and then set the text of the text edit to the result of the shared preferences? or did I get the whole idea wrong?

Comment: @Baruch , You do have the right idea. Lets see what happens and then i will tell you.

Comment: Ok I'll, post an answer soon when I get on my computer so I'll see if what I  have in mind does work

Comment: @Baruch,Been trying to solve this on my own for a week but there are no results yet.

Comment: I didn't get to be on my PC today, had a long day, but in my theory, just saving the information variable by variable and then when the dialog loads again, just setting the text edit or text area by var.setText() if available should do the trick, I'll look more deeply into it tomorrow, good luck!

Comment: @Baruch, I finally solved it. Thanks for your input. I will post fresh code later in the day. I could not sleep just thinking about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably use `SharedPreferences` and store the information there, and then set the text of the text edit to the result of the shared preferences? or did I get the whole idea wrong?

here is an example of a simple save function:

```
  SharedPrefrences scores = getSharedPreferences("key_name_here", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = scores.edit();
  editor.putInt("key1", key1Var);
  editor.putInt("key2", key2Var);
  editor.commit();
```

and to retrive:

```
  Var = getPrefrences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("key1",default value);
```

That should probably do the trick

Comment: I tried it my way but your way is better. Thank you very much.